# Extending a generic class with and without types gives different implement methods in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, apache-flink

I was trying to extend the `org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat` class in Apache Flink that has the following signature

```
public abstract class FileInputFormat<OT> extends RichInputFormat<OT, FileInputSplit> {}
```

For completeness, the signature of the `RichInputFormat` class is,

```
public abstract class RichInputFormat<OT, T extends InputSplit> implements InputFormat<OT, T> {}
```

It (the first class - `FileInputFormat`) has two abstract methods `public boolean reachedEnd()` and `public OT nextRecord(OT reuse)`

Now, if I extend with types as,

```
public class MyInputFormat<T> extends FileInputFormat<T>{}
```

then IntelliJ, as expected, suggests (Ctrl+I) to implement these two abstract methods, which is correct and needed to compile the program.

However, if I extend **without** types as,

```
public class MyInputFormat extends FileInputFormat{}
```

then IntelliJ suggests implementing two other methods in the `InputFormat` interface, which are already implemented in the `FileInputFormat` class. These methods are `public InputSplitAssigner getInputSplitAssigner(InputSplit[] inputSplits)` and `public void open(InputSplit split)`.

In fact, these are **not** necessary to compile the program, though one may prefer to override them.

Any logical reasoning for this behavior?

Comment: Extending without types does not make sense. If `MyInputFormat` should not be a generic class, you need to specify the actual data type you wanna use for FileInputFormat: `public class MyInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<TypeToUse> {}`

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was just wondering what causes this peculiar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a peculiarity of IntelliJ. The two additional methods that are suggested depend on some generic parameter defined in the super interface "InputFormat".

Apparently IntelliJ assumes the to additional methods should be overridden, when the generics types are dropped.

This looks almost like a small bug: When using a raw type in Java, the type parameters should default to their lower bound (here "Object" for "T").
But in this case, also the defined parameters of "FileInputFormat" (namely "FileInputSlit") are dropped.